# Duplicate entries being created via timers

Tags: c#

Essentially, I have created a program that simulates a petrol station that will save transactions made to a file, this is using a timer, however it will create multiple records of the same vehicle within the file.

transactions are put into a queue after they are created and I cycle through this list and add the transactions to the file however some vehicles fuel quicker than others and if the fuelling time takes more than a second (how often the transactions are checked to be outputted) then the for loop goes around again to start from the beginning causing duplicate entries into the file.

The only solution I could truly think of is to check the last line of the file and compare it to the file i'm about to write and say if its there don't write it but that wouldn't help for the other entries, i'm well and truly stuck here :/

```
//Writes the transactions to a file
string appendText = "£" + transaction.Cost.ToString() + ", " + transaction.Vehicle.TankSize.ToString() +" litres, " + transaction.Vehicle.PlateNumber.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
File.AppendAllText("HistoricTransactions.txt", appendText);
```

This being the writing to file

Comment: Do you not remove processed items from the queue?

Comment: Learn about the Singleton Pattern and add synchronization to it (Synchronized Singleton). The Singleton guarantee to create one instance only. https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton

Comment: @RossBush The program auto removes after 5 transactions are in the queue (part of assignment spec) but they just arent being replaced, I found a sort of fix which was just to move the process the another part of the program that utilises threaded timers and only procs when a vehicle is assigned to a pump meaning that i wont get duplicates anymore however i've now encountered a different issue with system.io but I'll make a new thread for it if i cant solve it :)

Comment: I strongly encourage you to provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: The code provided doesn't tell us anything about what might be causing the problems you mention. We need to see the `Timer` code as well as the overall structure.